# Does tramp offer any API for interrogating information from the buffer-file-name

Tags: emacs, tramp

I'm currently doing a lot of work on remote machines with tramp. However the project logic gets confused when building make command lines as it will attempt to cd to some /ssh:blah.... path.

Does tramp provide any API functions to test if a buffer or a buffer filename is actually managed by tramp and therefor on a remote machine? Can it provide additional information about the type of connection (for example ssh user/host details)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As to your first question about checking if a filename is managed by tramp, see the function tramp-tramp-file-p, which will return t if filename is a tramp file.

Comment: `tramp-tramp-file-p` does *not* return `t` for a Tramp file, it actually returns `0`, which happens to be the index returned by `string-match` which is used to check Tramp filename syntax. I am inclined to say that this is a bug, either in `tramp-tramp-file-p`'s docstring or in its implementation. I would recommend using `file-remote-p` for testing if a file is remote, because it is more generic (it should be able to handle other remote access handlers besides Tramp).

Answer (score 2):

The variable `tramp-file-name-regexp` is used to match Tramp-like filenames. *(edit: see erikriverson's answer below for a more convenient way to match against this.)*

This is added to `file-name-handler-alist` (which determines the handler for all filenames), and associated with `tramp-file-name-handler`, so you could alternatively test the return value of the `find-file-name-handler` function to see whether it matches. This seems like a slightly more robust method (although in practice it probably makes no difference).

`(eq (find-file-name-handler filename nil) 'tramp-file-name-handler)`

`(tramp-dissect-file-name filename)` will then return the individual connection components (also see the `tramp-file-name-structure` variable).